# Java. Wildcards in Collections

Tags: java, collections, wildcard

Java. Wildcards in Collections

I’m having a lot of trouble understanding wildcards in Collections, even after reading similar posts in Stack Overflow and various tutorials sites. I've made a very simple example below. Can you explain how I would choose between `Collection< myClass >`,  `Collection< ? Extends MyClass >`, and `Collection< ? Super MyClass >`?

```
package z5;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Z5 {
public static class Animal{
}
public static class Mammal extends Animal{   
}
public static class Reptile extends Animal{   
}
public static class Lion extends Mammal{   
}
public static class Tiger extends Mammal{   
}
public static class Snake extends Reptile{
}           
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Mammal> catHouse1 = new ArrayList<Mammal>();
            catHouse1.add(new Lion());
            catHouse1.add(new Tiger());  
            catHouse1.add(new Mammal());
            catHouse1.add(new Animal()); //ERROR  
        ArrayList<? super Mammal> catHouse2 = new ArrayList<Mammal>();
            catHouse2.add(new Lion());
            catHouse2.add(new Tiger());
            catHouse2.add(new Mammal());
            catHouse2.add(new Animal()); //ERROR  
        ArrayList<? extends Mammal> catHouse3 = new ArrayList<Mammal>();
            catHouse3.add(new Lion());  //ERROR
            catHouse3.add(new Tiger());  //ERROR
            catHouse3.add(new Mammal());  //ERROR
            catHouse3.add(new Animal()); //ERROR 
        ArrayList<Mammal> zooMammals = new ArrayList<Mammal>();
            zooMammals.addAll(catHouse1);  
            zooMammals.addAll(catHouse2);  //ERROR
            zooMammals.addAll(catHouse3);
        ArrayList<Animal> zooAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
            zooAnimals.addAll(catHouse1);
            zooAnimals.addAll(catHouse2);  //ERROR
            zooAnimals.addAll(catHouse3);        
    }
}
```

In the example above, I make a hierarchy of classes. Animal is the superclass of Mammal and Reptile, and Mammal is the superclass of Lion and Tiger.

I make ArrayLists for three Cat Houses in my zoo. The first is simply ArrayList< Mammal >. I can add any Object of type Mammal or its subclasses.

The second is ArrayList< ? super Mammal>. I can also add any Object of type Mammal or its subclasses.

The third is ArrayList< ? extends Mammal>. I can't add anything to it.

Finally, I add my three cat houses into zoo Collections. Animal and Mammal are the main superclasses here, and the behavior is the same regardless of which type the recipient ArrayList holds.
ArrayList < Mammal > and ArrayList can be added to the zoos.
ArrayList  cannot.

Here are my questions:

---

1) If I want to make an array that holds all subclasses of a certain superclass, why would I need a wildcard? Couldn't I just declare everything ArrayList< Superclass > and get the functionality I need?

2) I understand that "< ? extends superclass >" accepts the superclass and all its subclasses. Ergo, < ? extends Mammal >" accepts Mammals, Lions, and Tigers. That sounds exactly like "< Mammal >". What's the difference?

3) I read that "< ? super className >" accepts any class that's a superclass of className. That doesn't sound right. In the example above, Lions are not superclasses of Mammals, but "< ? super Mammal >" accepts Lions. Animals are superclasses of Mammals, but "< ? super Mammal >" doesn't accept it. I think I have wrong information there.

4) If "< ? extends superclass >" is read-only, how dod I populate it to begin with? And what's the point of having an empty list that you can only read from?

5) Why does the addAll method not work on "< ? super className >"?

I know these are fundamental questions, and I understand they've been answered before. I'm trying to give a code example that's as simple as possible and hopefully get me an answer that's as clear as possible. Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't go into great details.

`List<Animal>` means: this list contains instances of Animal. So you can add any Animal you want, and you're sure to get an Animal when getting elements from this list.

`List<? extends Animal>` means: this list is a generic list, but we don't know the type of the generic type. All we know about it is that the generic type is Animal, or any subclass of Animal. So it could be a `List<Animal>`, a `List<Reptile>` or a `List<Lion>`, for example. But we don't know. So, when getting an element from this list, you're guaranteed to get an Animal. But you won't be allowed to add anything into the list, because you don't know its type. If you were allowed to add something, you could store a Lion in a `List<Reptile>`, and the list wouldn't be type-safe anymore.

`List<? super Animal>` means: this list is a generic list, but we don't know the type of the generic type. All we know about it is that the generic type is Animal, or any superclass or super interface of Animal. So it could be a `List<Animal>` or a `List<Object>`, for example. So, when getting an element from this list, all you can say for sure is that it's an Object. What you can do for sure is to add any Animal you want in this list though, because both `List<Animal>` and `List<Object>` accept Animal, Lion, Reptile or whatever subclass of Animal.

Most of the time, you use these wildcards for arguments of your methods.

When a method takes a list as argument and is only interested in reading from the list (i.e. the list is a producer), you'll use `List<? extends Animal>`. This makes your method more reusable, because it can be used with a `List<Animal>`, but also with a `List<Reptile>`, a `List<Lion>`, etc.

When a method takes a list as argument and is only interested in adding elements to the list (i.e. the list is a consumer), you'll use `List<? super Animal>`. This makes your method more reusable, because it can be used with a `List<Animal>`, but also with a `List<Object>`.

This rule is known as PECS: *Procucer: Extends; Consumer: Super*.

If your method takes a list as argument and must both get and add elements to/from the list, you'll use a `List<Animal>`.

Comment: "Most of the time, you use these wildcards for arguments of your methods."    Thank you, thank you, thank you. I was trying to understand this from creating a Collection of particular types, and I couldn't find a good reason to do that (still can't). But I hadn't thought of it as an argument type for a method. Wildcards make methods more usable because it allows them to be used by many different Collection types.

Comment: So, in my main method holds Lists of Reptiles and Mammals and Amphibians to keep track of everything in the zoo, I should declare those list types as their particular superclasses: List< Mammal >, List< Reptile >, List < Amphibian >, etc.

Comment: If I have methods I want to use on all the animals, I should declare their arguments with wildcards: public double totalWeight (List<? extends Animal> l){//a foreach loop to add each animal object's weight and return the average}

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list that can contain `Animal` or subclasses `Animal` you should use `List<Animal>`. I think this is what you need most of the time.

**extends:**

```
ArrayList<? extends Mammal> list = ..
```

This means that `list` is of type `Mammal` **or** one of its sub classes. So you can do this:

```
ArrayList<? extends Mammal> list = new ArrayList<Tiger>(); // List of type Tiger
```

When using `<? extends Mammal>` you can't insert anything into `list` (except `null`). The reason that there is no typesafe way to insert anything. You can't add a `Mammal` to `list` because `list` might be of type `Tiger` (like in the example above). A `Mammal` is no `Tiger` so this can't work.

You can't add a `Tiger` to `list` either. That's because `<? extends Mammal>` doesn't tell you anything about `Tiger`. It would be also possible that `list` is of type `Lion`.

**super:**

With `<? super Mammal>` it is the opposite situation. `<? super Mammal>` means that the list is of type `Mammal` **or** one of its superclasses. You can do this:

```
ArrayList<? super Mammal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>(); // List of type Animal
```

You can add any subclass of `Mammal` to this list. This is safe because subclasses of `Mammal` are always subclasses of `Animal`. However you can't get anything out of the list with another type than `Object`. Thats because you don't know the exact list type.

```
Mammal m = list.get(0); // can't work because list can be a List<Animal>
```